# ClickOnce ReportBuilder 2.0 not working with Sharepoint

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-builder2.0

I just created a SSRS with SQL Server 2008 and Sharepoint (WSS 3.0), and believe I made the mistake of installing ReportBuilder 2.0 before installing Sharepoint.

So, the recommended custom lanch URL for REportBuilder does not work: /_vti_bin/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_2_0_0_0.application
It comes up with the error: The page cannot be found

I'm not sure why this happens.  Both ReportBuilder.application (1.0) and ReportBuilder_2_0_0_0.application are in the same folder but only ReportBuilder.application works.

I would reinstall ReportBuilder, but how would I do that?  I do not see any option to uninstall the ClickOnce version.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I created a virtual directory in IIS to point to the misplaced version of Report Builder which was located in this directory:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.SQL2008\Reporting Services\ReportServer\ReportBuilder`